# How to make a composable automatically recompose with the new value whenever a global variable changes its value?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to achieve this supposedly simple task for days to no avail. I tried consulting ChatGPT but it only provides non-working solutions. I tried doing this using `by remember { mutableStateOf() }`, `by rememberUpdatedState`, using `derivedStateOf`, storing the value in a global var inside a ViewModel class (because some sources say this is where you should store Compose-related data?). Nothing. I don't understand what is required and neither does ChatGPT.

The code is a bit convoluted to post in fractions, so I'll explain the basic hierarchal flow:
The upper function creates a BoxWithConstraints and within it a Row->calls other functions which create a Column->call other functions that create a Box->calls a function which fills the Box with buttons; and (within BoxWithConstraints after the Row) a Box that should hold an updating list of "child Buttons" (through a Button-creating function call) and an updating Modifier according to what "parent Button" was pressed. This Box is to be rendered as a floating window above the rest of the UI whenever a parent Button is pressed. When a child Button from within this Box nested in index i is pressed, it should trigger a change in the values of the parent Button so that the parent Button displays the name (or icon) of the child Button (stored in  `listOfAllButtons[i].childButtons[listOfAllButtons[i].childButtonIndex].name`).

Because the child Buttons are not actually hierarchically children of the parent Buttons (I'm not even sure this is possible in Compose), my thought was storing all Button-related data in a global list of ButtonData type, and then for example when a child Button is pressed have a 'childButtonIndex' variable within ButtonData update to the appropriate value corresponding to the childButtons (a nested list of ButtonData within ButtonData) index, which should then trigger the appropriate parent Button to recompose with the updated data.

I can't figure any way of doing that. Nothing. The only way I saw any parent Button update to the new value of a global variable is if I added to its onClick parameter a line that assigns the local "remember variable" again with the value of the global variable, and then clicked that button again after the global value has already changed. That of course doesn't really provide the correct behavior. What needs to happen is that pressing a child Button right away triggers a recomposition with the new value in the parent Button.

Help?

Comment: Can you break this down to a minimal example of what you want? There’s a lot of talk about various details of the UI that might not be relevant.

Comment: @Tenfour4 I think the title summarizes it up. I want that if, for example, the Text element for one button is Text(text = globalString), when that globalString changes in value (for example when pressing a different button sends it a new value) that the button would recompose with the new globalString value as its text.

Comment: Sorry, the other part I forgot to ask is exactly what you mean by global. Global usually means a top-level property (in a singleton `object` or not in any class at all) that lives for the entire lifetime of an app. But you mention it being in a ViewModel, which contradicts that. So what is the lifecycle of this "globalString" in comparison to the Composable?

Comment: @TLSO the thing that can trigger recomposition is state variables so you should put your "globalString" inside a mutableState variable and put it as a text in button and whenever the string changes it will recompose the button

Comment: @Tenfour04 I tried both situations, at first as a top-level property (as an object) and later also within a ViewModel because it was somehow suggested this is the right way to hold composable information, but neither triggered recomposition when the referenced value has changed.

Comment: @AymanAit If you're talking about declaring in the composable scope a variable by remember{ mutableStateOf(globalVariable) }, I tried that before and it didn't update on its own. I now tried (assuming this is what you suggested?) to change the relevant variables in my ButtonData class (which as mentioned gets instantiated in a mutableListOf<ButtonClass>) to MutableState<T> so it is a MutableState at the source - still didn't trigger recomposition in the buttons. (cont)

Comment: @AymanAit ... They seem to recompose only when a local parameter in the composable changes through interaction with the composable itself, regardless of whether the global variable whose value it reads is declared as a MutableState<T> or a regular Type. So... What gives? It seems the "remember", "Mutable", "State" and anything else don't matter and that the only thing that does affect anything is whether a parameter in the composable is directly interacted with or not.

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of changing the value of a mutable state that you’re trying that’s not working? MutableState is the way to do it. `remember` is an extra thing needed if your state is declared within a Composable since it needs to outlast recomposition in order to work.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I was in the middle of editing my question to add some code snippets when I noticed one point in my code where I equalized during a click on the 'childButton' a mutableState<Int> to another mutableState, instead of their .value, so I had on the parentButton's onClick this: 'text = listOfAllButtons[buttonData.buttonIndex.value].childButtons[listOfAllButtons[buttonData.buttonIndex.value].childButtonIndex.value].name.value', but on the child's onClick: 'listOfAllButtons[buttonData.parentButtonIndex.value].childButtonIndex = buttonData.buttonIndex'. 

'childButtonIndex.value =' works!

Answer (score 0):

I'll summarize the solution as it was really simple:

Any value used by one composable which needs to be updated through the interaction with another composable should be declared at the top-level as a `MutableState<T>`, and any updates to its value should be done as `MutableState<T>.value = MutableState<T>.value` in order to trigger recomposition.

At one point I had a specific `MutableState<Int>` that I also needed to update between different buttons get updated in an onClick scenario like this:
`MutableState<Int> = MutableState<Int>`

As the '.value' part was missing it didn't automatically trigger recomposition.